# How can I define NFData instance for recursive singleton type?

Tags: haskell, type-families, type-level-computation

I'm using `singletons` library. I have this data type:

```
import Control.DeepSeq
import Data.Singletons.Prelude
import Data.Singletons.TH

data T =
      A
    | B [T]

genSingletons [''T]
```

I want generated singleton type `ST` to be instance of `NFData`.
It would be straightforward if type `T` wouldn't be recursive.
I tried to write this:

```
instance NFData (ST a) where
    rnf SA = ()
    rnf (SB (x `SCons` xs)) = rnf x `seq` rnf xs
```

but this fails on last line with message:

```
Could not deduce (NFData (Sing n1)) arising from a use of `rnf'
from the context (a ~ 'B n)
  bound by a pattern with constructor
             SB :: forall (z_azEs :: T) (n_azEt :: [T]).
                   (z_azEs ~ 'B n_azEt) =>
                   Sing n_azEt -> Sing z_azEs,
           in an equation for `rnf'
or from (n ~ (n0 : n1))
  bound by a pattern with constructor
             SCons :: forall (a0 :: BOX) (z0 :: [a0]) (n0 :: a0) (n1 :: [a0]).
                      (z0 ~ (n0 : n1)) =>
                      Sing n0 -> Sing n1 -> Sing z0,
           in an equation for `rnf'
In the second argument of `seq', namely `rnf xs'
In the expression: rnf x `seq` rnf xs
In an equation for `rnf':
    rnf (SB (x `SCons` xs)) = rnf x `seq` rnf xs
```

I understand that GHC wants `x` and `xs` in pattern ``` SB (x ``SCons`` xs)) ``` to be instances of `NFData`, but I have trouble figuring out how exactly to tell this.
What should I write in the context of this instance to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to provide `NFData` instances for singleton lists.

```
instance NFData (SList '[]) where
  rnf SNil = ()

instance (NFData (Sing x), NFData (SList xs)) => NFData (SList (x ': xs)) where
  rnf (SCons x xs) = rnf x `seq` rnf xs
```

Note that you can't solve this in a single instance, because that way you couldn't provide the recursive `NFData` constraints:

```
instance NFData (SList xs) where
  rnf SNil = ()
  rnf (SCons x xs) = ? -- no way to know if NFData (Sing x)
```

Similarly, you have to write separate instances for the `T` cases:

```
instance NFData (ST A) where
  rnf SA = ()

instance NFData (SList xs) => NFData (ST (B xs)) where
  rnf (SB xs) = rnf xs
```

Comment: What is the purpose of NFData?

Comment: @jonaprieto [See the docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq-1.4.2.0/docs/Control-DeepSeq.html).