# How to fully evaluate a recursive data type using Control.DeepSeq in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, strictness, haskell-criterion

I am trying to benchmark (with [Criterion](http://www.serpentine.com/criterion/tutorial.html)) a function, which uses a recursive data type. I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31477176/how-can-i-define-nfdata-instance-for-recursive-singleton-type) with an answer that I haven't been able to apply for my case. For non-recursive data types, the following works:

```
data ExampleDataType1 a = 
    ValueConst1 String String String String 
  | ValueConst2 String String
  | ValueConst3 a
  | ValueConst4 String        
deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)


instance DeepSeq.NFData a => DeepSeq.NFData (ExampleDataType1 a) where
    rnf (ValueConst1 c1 c2 c3 c4) = DeepSeq.rnf c1 `seq` DeepSeq.rnf c2 `seq` DeepSeq.rnf c3 `seq` DeepSeq.rnf c4
    rnf (ValueConst2 c1 c2)       = DeepSeq.rnf c1 `seq` DeepSeq.rnf c2
    rnf (ValueConst3 c1)          = DeepSeq.rnf c1
    rnf (ValueConst4 c2)          = DeepSeq.rnf c2
```

However, doing the following:

```
infixl 6 :+: -- Addition
infixl 7 :*: -- Multiplication
data ExampleDataType2 a =

    ValueConst5 (ExampleDataType2 a) 
    | a :*: String    
    | (ExampleDataType2 a) :+: (ExampleDataType2 a)      
    | ValueConst6 String a     
    | ValueConst7 String a     
    deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

type MapExample a b = Map.Map String (Either (ExampleDataType1 a) (ExampleDataType2 b))

data ExampleDataType3 a b = ExampleDataType3 {
    start :: String,
    mapList :: [MapExample a b]

    } deriving Show


instance DeepSeq.NFData a => DeepSeq.NFData (ExampleDataType1 a) where
    rnf (ValueConst1 c1 c2 c3 c4) = DeepSeq.rnf c1 `seq` DeepSeq.rnf c2 `seq` DeepSeq.rnf c3 `seq` DeepSeq.rnf c4
    rnf (ValueConst2 c1 c2)       = DeepSeq.rnf c1 `seq` DeepSeq.rnf c2
    rnf (ValueConst3 c1)          = DeepSeq.rnf c1
    rnf (ValueConst4 c2)          = DeepSeq.rnf c2 

instance DeepSeq.NFData b => DeepSeq.NFData (ExampleDataType2 b) where
    rnf (ValueConst5 c1)           = DeepSeq.rnf c1
    rnf (val1 :+: val2)            = DeepSeq.rnf val1 `seq` DeepSeq.rnf val2
    rnf (val :*: str)              = DeepSeq.rnf val `seq` DeepSeq.rnf str
    rnf (ValueConst6 str val)      = DeepSeq.rnf str `seq` DeepSeq.rnf val
    rnf (ValueConst7 str val)      = DeepSeq.rnf str `seq` DeepSeq.rnf val

instance (DeepSeq.NFData a, DeepSeq.NFData b) => DeepSeq.NFData (ExampleDataType3 a b) where
    rnf (ExampleDataType3 s lst) =  DeepSeq.rnf s `seq` DeepSeq.rnf lst
```

results in an error, when calling the `nf` function of `Criterion.Main` on the function I wish to benchmark, which has the signature `testFunction :: (Show a1, Integral a1, Num a2, Eq a2) => [[a1]] -> ExampleDataType3 a2 a1`:

```
• Ambiguous type variable ‘a20’ arising from a use of ‘nf’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Control.DeepSeq.NFData
                                  a20)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a20’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance [safe] (Control.DeepSeq.NFData a,
                         Control.DeepSeq.NFData b) =>
                        Control.DeepSeq.NFData (Either a b)
          -- Defined in ‘Control.DeepSeq’
        instance (Control.DeepSeq.NFData k, Control.DeepSeq.NFData a) =>

                 Control.DeepSeq.NFData (Map.Map k a)
          -- Defined in ‘Data.Map.Internal’
        instance Control.DeepSeq.NFData a =>
                 Control.DeepSeq.NFData (Set.Set a)
          -- Defined in ‘Data.Set.Internal’
        ...plus 20 others
        ...plus 150 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
```

I would appreciate every answer on how one should fully evaluate a recursive data type.

Edit 1:

The benchmark call that causes the error:

```
main = defaultMain [
            bgroup "TestCases" [ bench "Case 1" $ nf testFunction [[1,0,1,1],[0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,0],[0,1,0,1]]
                         ]]
```

The function `testFunction` does its job as desired except I fail to fully evaluate the recursive data type so that `nf` function of Criterion can accept my function as an input. Therefore, I would like to avoid changing the data type.

Comment: It's always helpful to include a way for other to reproduce your error.

Comment: This is just a small part of a big bachelor's thesis project, which I am not allowed to share publicly. However, I am adding the benchmark call of Criterion, that causes this error. I dont know if that makes any difference though

Comment: Have you tried doing what GHC suggests in its "probable fix"...?

Comment: I am not sure, how I can do its suggestion without changing the data type definitions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a type signature to `testFunction` where you pass it to `nf`.  Something like:

`nf (testFunction :: [[Int]] -> ExampleDataType3 Double Int) [[1,0,1,1],[0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,0],[0,1,0,1]]`

I picked the type Double; you may pick some other type.  Since there are several options, GHC gives the `Ambiguous type variable` error rather than arbitrarily picking one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I thought the problem was occuring due to compiler not being able to resolve the recursive data type, since the other variant was working fine without explicitly adding the type signature. Therefore, I haven't consider adding the signature explicitly.